# Twitter API getting 401 error

Tags: jquery, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have JQuery Twitter api plugin I have been using often from site to site ([from here](http://www.queness.com/post/8881/create-a-twitter-feed-with-attached-images-from-media-entities)). Ive recently installed it on a new site but now get a 401 error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
jsonp1342737708184({"error":"This method requires authentication.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json\/?callback=jsonp1342737708184&include_rts=true&count=3&include_entities=true"})
```

The line the error is referring looks like:

```
  at: function(tweet) {
            return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function(m, username) {
                    return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
                                });
                            },
```

I think this has something to do OAuth authentication but I am unsure of how to go about updating my script.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5025 #might_help `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: I had not configured my Script to handle the user name correctly. As you can see in the error there is no username present. My username var had a mistake in it.

Thanks!